# Add an enable and disable validation button on front page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, frontend, client-side

all
I am recently dealing with data validation by using client side. I was wondering would it be possible to add a button on form page to turn on or turn off (before submit the form) validation (client side) as user's wish to store the incompelted form.
What I have now: I set a stage column in database to indicate if the model require validation:

```
validates_category :category_id, unless: :raw_data?
```

But it looks impossible to change the stage through submit form. Since the behavior of changing stage will be blocked by client side.

Sorry for blunt of my language, generally, the button function is to force save form to database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make a button in form with some JS attached which disables validation in the form, and adds some hidden field to that form. Then in controller just check if the request has that parameter from hidden field set or not and if then just use `.save!` (which forces save do DB) instead of `save`?